# Simple WPF page selection for multipaged tiff

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, image-manipulation, tiff

I am making a basic Tiff viewer and need to be able to select the page to be viewed. In Winforms I could use selectActiveFrame, so I was wondering if there is a WPF equivalent for this. Thanks!

EDIT: In winforms I used System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension in the selectActiveFrame method if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TiffBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder.aspx) class to load the image and then use the [Frames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder.frames.aspx) property to access which tiff frame you like.