# How to display a multiple page TIFF image in my WPF application with VB.net code-behind

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a SQL server table with a field that stores binary data.  The binary data is of "muliple page TIFF" image\file.
I want to display this multiple page Tiff image\file in my WPF application, using a scroll viewer, a viewbox, and image controls.
How can I do this?

I need both XAML and VB.Net code-behind samples.

Thank you,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004185/wpf-image-control-to-progressively-load-multipage-tiff

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried the following. Works when testing because I have a file saved in an actual file path:                                                                                                                 Dim imageStreamSource As New FileStream("C:\MyFiles\LETTER_A_EXAMPLE_XYZ.tif", FileMode.Open)
        Dim decoder As New TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default)
        Dim bitmapSource As BitmapSource = decoder.Frames(0)
        SVimage1.Source = bitmapSource

Comment: The problem is that in reality I don't have a file path.  The image is store as binary in a field, in a SQL Database.  If I could get TiffBitMapDecoder with my binary data and then get the number of frames, that would be great!!!!